# Blog suddenly can't display .jpg

Tags: uploads, media

I’ve been managing https://Barrett.Lang-Learn.org for a fellow who self-describes as technology-illiterate.  He recently told me his header image has disappeared.

I logged in and went to the media library.  The header image and two other uploads are shown as "file not found" icons.  In a shell, I verified that the file is in the indicated location: `uploads/2016/01/header.jpg` and is a JPG that a graphics program has no problem displaying.  And if I bypass wordpress, `http://barrett.lang-learn.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/header.jpg` appears as expected.  But Wordpress no longer displays it.  I have other blogs, all with the same (latest) version of Wordpress, and they do not have this problem.

I did recently change `.htaccess`, but I made the same change in all of them (copied the same file) and then changed them all back.  I see nothing in `.htaccess` to explain this.

I checked the permissions, and everything is world-readable as expected.

Anyone have an explanation or a fix?

Comment: Seems likes an issue with SSL certificate. Image loads fine if accessed directly in browser or a http version of the image is loaded in the webpage.

Also, the server returns this "
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /wp-content/plugins/email-subscribers/lite/public/images/spinner.gif on this server.

If this is your Web site and you're not sure why you're seeing this message, the permissions on this file may be set incorrectly: the file should be world-readable.
"

Comment: Currently, due to a screw-up I did last night, images are now blocked by .htaccess but I still don't know why they were blocked before.

Comment: I removed the4 mistake I made last night, and I must have in the process removed whatever was blocking them before.  Because now they are working.

Comment: That's great. You can add your answer and accept it as answer.